# M_P is deprecated: Please use 'Double.pi' or '.pi' to get the value of correct type and avoid casting in Swift 3.1

Tags: swift, swift3

I have this error when updating my codes to **Swift3.1** with **Xcode 8.3.1**

> 'M_PI' is deprecated: Please use 'Double.pi' or '.pi' to get the value of correct type and avoid casting.

My codes under below,

```
let center     = containerShapeView.center
let startAngle = CGFloat(0.0)
let endAngle   = CGFloat(M_PI*2)
let radius     = containerShapeView.bounds.width * 0.21
```

**CGFloat(M_PI*2)** line gives error

How can I resolve it ?

Comment: Is there an error if you just do what the message says?

Comment: Wow, what on earth is the hard part of _this_?

Comment: @matt At least this will serve to help people in the future who rather ask SO question than read error messages :|

Comment: idk what's wrong with question. I didn't know that CGFloat has .pi in it. So question turns to be helpful anyway, at least more helpful that documentation.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Well, follow the instructions of the error message:

```
let center     = containerShapeView.center
let startAngle = CGFloat(0.0)
let endAngle   = CGFloat(Double.pi) * 2
let radius     = containerShapeView.bounds.width * 0.21
```

Or better yet, to avoid the unecessary conversions:

```
let center     = containerShapeView.center
let startAngle: CGFloat = 0
let endAngle   = CGFloat.pi * 2
let radius     = containerShapeView.bounds.width * 0.21
```

Comment: Small typo: `endAngle` is `CGFloat.pi * 2`

Comment: @SilvanMosberger Thanks, fixed.

Comment: best solve for this case   
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0, options:[], animations: {
            // -0.0000001 for the rotation direction control
            self.arrow.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi-0.0000001))
        }, completion:nil)

Comment: @islamXDeveloper are you responding to the wrong post?